# Calling server stored procedure using binding

Tags: mysql, qt, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a MySQL server stored procedure using Qt. The procedure returns multiple rows of data I want to retrieve.

The first snippet I tried works fine:

```
QSqlQuery query("CALL GetOrderItems(323)", dataBase);
qDebug() << query.first();
```

It also returns the desired data and `query.first()` is true like expected.

Then I tried to insert the parameter using parameter binding like the Qt documentation proposes. I tried the following snippets. The first uses index placeholder the second keyword placeholder.

```
QSqlQuery query(dataBase);
qDebug() << query.prepare("CALL GetOrderItems(?)");
query.bindValue(0, 323);
qDebug() << query.exec();
qDebug() << query.first();

QSqlQuery query(dataBase);
qDebug() << query.prepare("CALL GetOrderItems(:myparam)");
query.bindValue(":myparam", 323);
qDebug() << query.exec();
qDebug() << query.first();
```

Both of these queries execute fine. But `query.first()` returns false so I don't know how the get the results.

Can I get the result from the binding queries in some way? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qmysql - seems to be a limitation in the MySQL driver/API.

Comment: The linked text says IN, OUT and INOUT parameters. But I do not use OUT or INOUT parmeters. I want to retrieve the query result records. I did not try to use an OUT parameter instead... but if the linked text is right that will fail too.

Comment: You're using `IN` parameters, are you not?

Comment: Yes but I think there is a problem with OUT and INOUT parameters only. After all the query is executed without error.

Comment: Quoting you: "The linked text says **IN**, OUT and INOUT parameters."

Comment: It actually says "no API to **control** IN, OUT and INOUT parameters" which can be interpreted differently. Anyway it seems the entire binding feature is useless in Qt. It is not supported fully (see your link), it seems not to return results (see my issue) and it does not support native batch mode. I will probably stop using it completely.

Comment: What do you think "control IN parameters" could mean other than being able to set them? That's the only thing you can do to them. Also read the sentence right after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sentences that can be found in the Qt documentation:

"MySQL 5 introduces stored procedure support at the SQL level, but no API to control IN, OUT and INOUT parameters." (from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql-stored-procedure-support), Thanks Mat)

"Stored procedures that uses the return statement to return values, or return multiple result sets, are not fully supported." (from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html))

So obviously binding parameters in Qt/MySQL is pretty useless. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765111/performance-when-using-batch-mode-of-qt-mysql) about batch mode.